# Facebook - Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to use the FB.ui() to send apprequests to friends. My application is a tab iframe app (NOT A CANVAS APP) so in my developers section, I only have the "Basic info" and "Page Tab" section complete (not the app on facebook area) as I do not want users to be able to directly go to the application.

the FB.UI() worked yesterday when I had the app of facebook area completed for my app, but when removing it I get the following error:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

The code I am using to send the messages is:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
                        message: 'Play RCS Let\'s make it happen game!'
                    }, function(data) {
                        $("#sendToFriends").fadeOut();
                        $("#didyouknow").fadeIn();
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

I dont mind completing the area for the "App of Facebook", but is that required and does that then make the above message notification url the app location or the page tab where the application is installed?

Any help will do!

Comment: I added the App on Facebook fields with the url of where my app is hosted and it worked.

Comment: You should accept the valid answer if it worked for you so that other can benefit from it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Populate the `App Domain:` and `Site URL:` fields in the Tab Settings. That will help with your problem. And you have to be sure that the Redirect URL matches the domain you specify.

Comment: Another Case: On IE if you get this issue and you are providing channelUrl - you can remove the channelUrl (which goes as redirect_uri) and issue will be fixed

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the page you are calling `FB.ui()` from has to match the domain that your app is set up to use in the facebook configuration.