# Authenticate a user from a page tab

Tags: authentication, facebook-page, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to make a Facebook page tab where people can vote for their favorite video or music track from a bunch of embedded files. I need to get a unique ID from each user to make sure that they can only vote once. The signed_request only contains the user's id if they have authorized my app.

I have tried to have users authorize my app using the FB.login() javascript api, but I get the error:

> **An error occurred with Remix // Rework Vote. Please try later**
>
> API Error Code: 191
>
> API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
>
> Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.

As far as I know, I have not set any redirect URL. Do I need to set this somewhere, or is this the not right approach to get a user to authenticate my page tab?

Comment: Do you have "App Domain" configured correctly in Application Settings?

Comment: @JuicyScripter No. It won't let me set one: `Error
You have specified an App Domain but have not specified a Site URL or a Mobile Web URL
[domain] must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web URL.` I can't see where to set those options, possibly because I am only using a page tab, not a site or mobile site.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify both "Site URL" (or "Mobile Web URL") and "App Domain" to use OAuth flow...

See where to fill the details on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#redirect-uris

Comment: Do I have to use OAuth flow or are there other valid ways in a page tab canvas page context? I have no particular desire to use OAuth, I just need to get a unique ID from Facebook, and `FB.login()` seemed to be what was needed according to documentation I found.

Comment: `FB.login` is using OAuth flow, so yes you required to use OAuth to authenticate the user.

Comment: Sure, but do I have to use `FB.login`, or are there other ways? AFAIK, `FB.login` might be completely the wrong thing for a page tab, it's just the first thing I found that sort of looked vaguely right.

Comment: The link starts with "When redirect_uris are specified in the authentication flows,". I'm not specifying any redirect URIs. I'm just calling FB.login from the first canvas page in my page tab.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get this to work by ticking "App on Facebook" in the app settings, and setting the `Canvas URL` and `Secure Canvas URL`s to be the same as the Page Tab URL equivalents.

This worked even though this isn't a full app, it's only a page tab, and it won't function as an app unless it's in a container page.

I'm guessing this is a bug in Facebook - the UI implies that you can have a page tab only app. The documentation doesn't say you can't, and I can't think of a good technical reason for it not to condsider a page tab URL as a valid URL.

Thanks to [@julio-santos](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/214773/julio-santos) for pointing me at [Facebook - Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8077140/3408), which seems to be the same problem in a slightly different context.