# How do I retrieve the list of people who liked my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve Facebook Fan Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001281/retrieve-facebook-fan-names)
>   [How to list facebook users who like a page or interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest)

in my project i want to retrieve the list of persons who have `liked` facebook my page. I want to get the `user details` and their `uids`.

A user may `Like` the page and once again he likes the page using a duplicate profile, so to avoid this type of things i want to get the `uid` of the person who like the page.

Is there any Api available for this...

Is it possible to get the uid value using the `batch request Api`

Is there any other way to get the uids  of the user, please help me friends..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple use this.

`https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=your page id`

It will return up to 500 of the most recent likes. Happy coding!

Comment: Hmm ... that may be true, but the data is pretty difficult to retrieve. This may also be a violation of Facebook's Terms of Service (?). And, of course, getting the next set of 500 will be tricky.

Comment: Yes, as with working with any third party API be it Facebook or another, you should always consult your corporate attorney to ensure your code doesn't violate any TOS or Policies.

Comment: Is there a way to get it using Graph API?

Comment: how to get my page id?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can get the ID of such users is to have an app running as a page tab. When the user loads your tab, and installs (i.e. gives permissions to) your app, the `signed_request` that Facebook sends to your server (along with the HTTP POST request for the page) will contain a `user_id`.

**tl;dr:** you won't get any IDs unless users install an app you made.

Comment: How do you request that a user gives permission to your page tab app?

Comment: This is the easiest way: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've been trying, but I can't get it to work: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/8945870/3408

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8077431/214773